# If $u$ is a unit, so is $-u$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that if $u$ is a unit in $R$ then so is $-u$.
I just started to study this chapter in abstract so i have no clue how to start thinking about ring in general. So if someone can elaborate that would be great thanks.

Comment: Write down what it means that $u$ is a unit. Then write down what it means for $-u$ to be a unit. If you do that, you should very quickly find the proof. For future questions do try to show some minimal effort. This type of questions don't really belong on MSE.

Comment: yeah you are right man. I feel embarrass that i even ask something like that in MSE

Comment: It is not true this question doesn't belong here. While simple, the proof is not a complete triviality. And, although some may try to force you, you don't need to show effort for someone to answer you. The amount of effort you put is your own choice.

Comment: Please try a more descriptive title than "basic question in ring theory", next time.

Answer (score 4):

Skipping some steps.

If $vu=1$. Let us show that $(-v)(-u)=1$.

---

> **Lemma 1:** $$0\cdot u=(0+0)\cdot u=0\cdot u+0\cdot u$$
>   Therefore $0\cdot u=0$. Similarly $u\cdot 0=0$.

---

> **Lemma 2:** $$\begin{align}0&=0\cdot0\\&=(1+(-1))\cdot(1+(-1))\\&=1\cdot 1+(-1)\cdot1+1\cdot(-1)+(-1)(-1)\\&=1+(-1)+(-1)+(-1)\cdot(-1)\\&=(-1)+(-1)\cdot(-1)\end{align}$$
>   Therefore $1=(-1)\cdot(-1)$

---

> **Lemma 3:** $$0=0\cdot u=(1+(-1))\cdot u=u+(-1)\cdot u$$
>   Therefore $(-1)\cdot u=-u$. Similarly $u\cdot (-1)=-u$.

---

Now we can check

$$\begin{align}(-v)\cdot(-u)&=((-1)\cdot v)\cdot((-1)\cdot u)\\&=(-1)\cdot u\cdot (-1)\cdot u\\&=(-1)\cdot (-v)\cdot u\\&=(-1)\cdot(-1)\cdot v\cdot u\\&=1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For any r(i)ng $R$, and for any $x, y \in R$
$$
(-x) = (-1) \times x
$$
and
$$
(-x) \times y = x \times (-y) = -(x \times y)
$$
and
$$
(-x) \times (-y) = x \times y.
$$

These can all be proved directly from the ring axioms.